# save Object with additional attributes in new nested object javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have an Object with arrays in it like:

```
entries = 
0: (2) ["manufacturer", "intel"]
1: (2) ["quantity", "20"]
2: (2) ["foo", "bar"]
```

(i know, not very concise)

Now i need to convert it to the following format to be able to pass it on and not cause crazy mixing of types further.

```
itemName:
0: {name: "manufacturer", value: "intel"}
1: {name: "quantity", value: "20"}
2: {name: "foo", value: "bar"}
```

Right now i do the following:

```
for (var [key, value] of entries) {
     // here i need to open up a new row in my object
     Object.assign(itemName, {name: key}, {value: value});
}
```

This returns the following:

```
{name: "foo", value: "bar"}
```

So it probably overwrites the first entries because they all have name, value.
Also i am not creating a new row for every name,value. What code could i add to this row.
Hope this is not too confusing

Comment: Is `entries` an array or an object ? Is `itemName` an array or an object ?

Comment: please define clearly !!! what you have and what you want ???

Comment: my bad.   entries is an array with arrays in it.      itemName is an object and i want/need an object as output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use map

```js
const data = [
  ["manufacturer", "intel"],
  ["quantity", "20"],
  ["foo", "bar"]
]

const final = data.map(([key, value]) => ({
  key,
  value
}))

console.log(final)
```

Comment: @AB Meg!!! In question entries was Object but in solution data is an array. then how